# angularjs directive template path not getting loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-templates

My current project structure is this

```
app/
   app1/
       login/
            app1.login.partials.html
       .
       .
       index.html
   app2/
   shared/
       login/
           login.directive.js
           login.partials.html
```

The code for login.directive.js is

```
angular.module('shared').directive('loginComponent', [ function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'login.partials.html',
        scope: {
            loginType: '@type'
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
        }
    };
}]);
```

The code for app1.login.paritals.html is simple

```
<login-component type="type1"></login-component>
```

When running app1, it refuses to load login.partials.html because of its path. The template loads only if I specify the path as `'../shared/login/login.html'`.
Is this due to the placement of index.html? Specifying a template path like above would kill the re-usability of the directive, as strict naming conventions would have to be followed

Comment: try 'app/shared/login/login.partials.html'.

Comment: It only works if index.html is in the same level as that of app folder. In this case the path would resolve like this - localhost:63342/angular-app/app/app1/app/shared/login/login.partials.html 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

index.html should place in project root.

```
app/
   index.html
   app1/
       login/
            app1.login.partials.html
       .
       .           
   app2/
   shared/
       login/
           login.directive.js
           login.partials.html
```

And then the path would be: 'app2/shared/login/login.partials.html'

Comment: The idea of each app having it's own index.html is because not all applications use all the shared components.

Comment: @BharathBhandarkar ah ok! then you can group the directives by modules  and inject in each app use it, like a external library.

Comment: That would be one possible solution I guess

Comment: @BharathBhandarkar Or you can pass a dynamic templateUrl path as attribute in the directive:
    templateUrl: function(element, attrributes){
        return attrributes.templateUrl || "defaultRoute.html";
       }